# Accessing the contentDocument of an iframe in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, phantomjs

I'm having difficulties accessing the contentDocument of an iframe. I am using phantomjs (1.9). I have looked into various threads but none seem to have the answer.

This is my phantomjs script where I have injected jquery to try and select the element.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
    console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg);
};

page.onError = function(msg) {
    console.log('ERROR MESSAGE: ' + msg);
};

page.open('http://localhost:8080/', function() {

    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {

        page.evaluate(function() {
            console.log( $('iframe').contentDocument.documentElement );
        });

        phantom.exit();
    });

});
```

Apart form jquery, I have also used these two lines of code to get the DOM element that I want (the DOM HTML element that's inside the iframe). PhantomJS seems unable to parse anything beyond getElementsByTagName('iframe') or $('iframe') could it be because it hasn't finished loading yet?

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument.activeElement;
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument.documentElement;
```

I am also running the script with --web-security=no setting disabled

Comment: No answers yet... hmm

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue but found it was because I was not wrapping the code in evaluate().  You seem to be doing that though.  Try this not using jquery.

```
page.evaluate(function (){
      iframe = document.getElementById('iframeName').contentDocument
      iframe.getElementById("testInput").value = "test";
});
```